# Развертывание deb-репозитория и ftp сервера

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, apt-get

Настроил deb репозиторий, локально по протоколу file:/ все работает. Для того чтобы расшарить его в сеть развернул ftp сервер, который тоже работает. Выставил опцию anonymous_enable=YES. Через терминал могу подключиться как anonymous.

В source.list добавил репозиторий. При выполнении sudo apt-get update выводится

`игн ftp://10.10.2.18 wily InRelease
игн ftp://10.10.2.18 wily Release.gpg
игн ftp://10.10.2.18 wily Release
[100%] ожидание заголовков`

В лог ftp сервер ничего не пишет, значит apt-get не может достучаться до машины с рерозиторием.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В лог ftp сервер ничего не пишет, значит apt-get не может достучаться до машины с рерозиторием.

неправильный вывод. файлы игнорируются потому, что сервер сообщил, что таких файлов нет. см. этот ответ: [How do Ign and Hit affect apt-get update?](https://superuser.com/a/454874/454489).

если бы возникли ошибки с доступом, *apt* так бы об этом и написал.

---

дополнение: насколько я понимаю, отсутствуют перечисленные файлы в каталоге `/корень-вашего-ftp/dists/wily/`.

Comment: Можете пояснить что значит игн? (Понянто что это игнор но почему?)
apt-get обращается к репозиторию по ftp, значит прежде всего идет обращение  к ftp серверу а уже потом через него к репозиторию, и следовательно ftp сервер должен был вывести в лог что к нему обращались, если этого нет значит обращения к нему не было -  разве не так?

Comment: да, я был не прав. поправил ответ.